# IDE With Continual Splitting

Tags: ide, split

I want to really learn which IDE can do continual splitting?
What about "Continual Splitting"? 
Try this:

Open a new file on open office writer. Paste into a long code, than do it:

```
View -> Zoom -> Columns : 2
```

If you dont do that you can't understand what i need. I know almost all IDEs can split but i dont need standart spliting.

Comment: As editors in IDEs are not really page-oriented - because code isn't - I don't think such a feature is high on implementors' todo lists...